# Navigation drawer closing with Back is broken in the support library v4 revision 20

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I have the navigation drawer in my app. After I've updated the support library v4 to revision 20 in the build.gradle I've noticed that the drawer doesn't close when open with Back key anymore. If I fall back to revision 19.1.0 all is ok. Have anyone experienced with this? Something was broken?

Comment: If you can compare the source code for both versions of `DrawerLayout.java`, check if anything has changed in this `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` methods.

Comment: I just recently updated from 19.1 to 22.2 and noticed the same behavior. For future readers here is a similar [**question with more answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26216088/708906), although none of them explain why the update broke the behavior. They do offer a workaround though.